# Difference between HystrixCommand and HystrixObservableCommand

Tags: java, hystrix

I m trying to understand the difference between HystrixCommand and HystrixObservableCommand. The reason i am confused is the HysterixCommand also has a observe() or toObservable() method which emit hot and cold observable respectively. So what was the need to create HystrixObservableCommand. If i will be working completely on non blocking calls which one should i use? why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Javadocs:

[HystrixCommand](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java)

> This command is essentially a blocking command but provides an Observable facade if used with observe()

[HystrixObservableCommand](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixObservableCommand.java)

> This command should be used for a purely non-blocking call pattern. The caller of this command will be subscribed to the Observable returned by the run() method.

The difference is that HystrixCommand by default supports a blocking paradigm, but also provides non-blocking behavior by way of Observables via a facade, whereas HystrixObservableCommand was implemented specifically for a non-blocking setup. I'm not entirely sure why it's split into two implementations, but I would guess that the reason is because originally HystrixCommand did not support non-blocking. It was added about [a year or so after the original implementation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/commit/c51bd7ef076ec1167ab81da4ac09cad371186a11). Could have just been cleaner to write a purely non-blocking hystrix class.

If you are working with only non-blocking calls, you should likely be using HystrixObservableCommand. Ben Christensen, one of the Hystrix devs, sums it up nicely in [this post:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hystrixoss/g7ZLIudE8Rs)

> However, if you are wrapping blocking calls, you should just stick
>   with using HystrixCommand as that’s what it’s built for and it
>   defaults to running everything in a separate thread. Using
>   HystrixCommand.observe() will give you the concurrent, async
>   composition you’re looking for.
>
> HystrixObservableCommand is intended for wrapping around async,
>   non-blocking Observables that don’t need extra threads.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to the answer of Nick Defazio, an implementation of `HystrixObservableCommand` wrap Observables that can emit multiple items, whereas `HystrixCommand`, will never emit more than one item, even when invoking `observe()` or `.toObservable()` *which are only wrapping the single value retuned by the `run()` method*.