# When use HystrixCommand and when use HystrixObservable?

Tags: hystrix

I read about but I'm in doubt when use Command or Observable..

Could someone give me some examples?

Thanks!!

I know that `Command.execute` is synchronous but I want to know **why** synchronous or asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between HystrixCommand and HystrixObservableCommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569560/difference-between-hystrixcommand-and-hystrixobservablecommand)

Comment: If possibel I want an Use Case for synchronous and asynchronous :/

Comment: Below link could be useful-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569560/difference-between-hystrixcommand-and-hystrixobservablecommand